# Problems with multi-language site using Umbraco

Tags: href, multilingual, umbraco7

I have set up a multi language site with Umbraco 7 based on this article:https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Using-Umbraco/Multilanguage-Setup/

I have managed to get the general layout and first level working but am having problems with the internal links.

For example:

```
                <ul>
                <li><a href="/">@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Home")</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/articles">@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Articles")</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I would expect the href to send to the content based on the current language.

My content is split as described in the article.
I have multiple logical sites: myip/en, myip/he etc/

I would have expected that a click on the articles link would take me to myip/en/articles if I was on the English site.
Instead it looks for myip/articles.

I have tried with and without the "/" and with and without a "~" before the slash. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco does not replace links in your code, so what you expected will not work. Another thing is that "article" is properly not the same word in the "he" language. Its also bad for SEO in the url.

You need to find the "article" node and then use `.Url` to get the url for this node. One way do to it would be:

```
@CurrentPage.DescendantsOrSelf("Article").First().Url
```

(assuming your template is called Article and your are on the root node)

If you really want ":lang/article" in your url no matter what language you are on, you could create a new Dictionary item called "SiteLang", and then write "en" in *en* and "he" in *he* language.

You could then create a link like this:

```
<li><a href="@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("SiteLang")/articles">@umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("Articles")</a></li>
```

Comment: I am confused. In the examples it shows a tree structure under each language node. How does it work? This is shown here in the post by "Rik Helsen": https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/2814-MultiLanguage-same-Domain-?p=3

Comment: A side question: Is there any way to insert a value from a cookie inside the href? I have the language name in a cookie so that would be much easier.

Comment: Yes, your site should be a tree structure as described in the forum. The links on your page should come from this site structure via the .Url propertry on each Node. About the cookiething.. it sounds like you are on the wrong path, but this should work: @Request.Cookies["cookiekey"]

Comment: I tried to use the .Url idea but couldn't figure out exactly how to use it. How would I write it in one of my examples?

Comment: .Url is a property of a node. It gives you the url to the specific node. You could use my first example, or simple write @CurrentPage.Url just to test it out.